# Using Generic List(Of Form), Trouble gathering Object's Name Property

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach, arraylist

I have been very interested as of late in interfaces and the ability to further customize them beyond using them in their default state.

I have been researching IList(of T) specifically. The advantages of using generic lists as opposed to ArrayLists has astounded me. Here is a picture of a [test](http://0.tqn.com/d/visualbasic/1/0/7/C/gen04.gif). This is the site that goes into further explanation [about the Test](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/vbnetspecialtopics/a/gen01_2.htm).

So, naturally I wanted to experiment. When I first iterate through the list with the ForNext method the code works fine. The second time I can't access the name of the Form in the list because it is disposed. Anyone have any insight how I can access the forms properties in the list.

```
Public Class frmMain

    Dim Cabinet As List(Of Form) = New List(Of Form)
    Dim FormA As New Form1
    Dim FormB As New Form2
    Dim FormC As New Form3

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _Me.Load

        Cabinet.Add(FormA)
        Cabinet.Add(FormB)
        Cabinet.Add(FormC)

    End Sub



    Sub displayForm(ByVal aForm As Form)

        Dim myFormName As String = ""

        Stopwatch.Start()

        If aForm.IsDisposed = False Then
            aForm.Show()
        Else
            myFormName = aForm.(How do I access this objects Name?) 
            aForm = New Form  '<----- I would rather simply use aForm = New(aForm) 
            aForm.Name = myFormName
            aForm.Show()

        End If

        Stopwatch.Stop()

        Dim RealResult As Decimal = (Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        Debug.WriteLine(RealResult)

        Stopwatch.Reset()

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnForEach_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnForEach.Click

        'Dim instance as List 
        'Dim action as Action(of T) 

        'instance.ForEach(action) 
        'action = delegate to a method that performs an action on the object passeed to it

        Cabinet.ForEach(AddressOf displayForm)
    End Sub
```

I really don't understand why if VB knows that this is a Generic list, which means it is knowledgable of the list's type, and the objects are all constrained to be forms; why I can't call a constructor on an item in the list. Ex. aForm = New aForm or aForm = New Cabinet.aForm

Tear this one open for me somebody. Thanks.

Comment: Well I just found that if I use Ctype(myListObject, Form) I can access the Form.text property. If anyone has 2 cents on this though, I want to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct a new instance of "aForm" because its isn't a type, it is an instance of type Form.

If you wanted to prevent the ObjectDisposedException, you could hide the form instead of closing it. Place the following code in each forms code behind:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Dim form = CType(sender, Form)
        form.Visible = False
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is a bit hacky, however, but then you wouldn't need the code in the `Else` block.

**Edit**
You could try this instead:

```
Private Sub displayForm(ByVal aForm As Form)

    Dim indexOfCab As Integer = Cabinet.IndexOf(aForm)
    If indexOfCab <> -1 Then

        If aForm.IsDisposed Then
            aForm = CreateForm(aForm.GetType())
            Cabinet(indexOfCab) = aForm
        End If

        aForm.Show()
    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Function CreateForm(formType As Type) As Form
    Return CType(Activator.CreateInstance(formType), Form)
End Function
```

You wouldn't need that big `Select` statement.

Comment: I like where your going with this but the form's resources would still be in use. This is just an excerpt from a much larger instance of the same code. I need to be able to have around twenty of these objects alive at once. I can't leave that many forms invisible. Points for creativity though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Andy! I was already playing with the Activator.CreateInstance, I just had not tried to Ctype aForm into a form. Very very nice. Bravo my friend and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I have been able to get it to work. I feel it is extremely inefficient however, and hope someone can set me on a path to a better way to do this. The below is what I'm trying to achieve.

**Sub displayForm(ByVal aForm As Form)**

```
   Dim myFormName As String = ""

   If Cabinet.Contains(aForm) Then

       Dim indexOfCab As Integer = Cabinet.IndexOf(aForm)
       Dim ObjForm As Form = Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab)

       If aForm.IsDisposed Then

           Select Case indexOfCab

               Case 0
                   aForm = Nothing
                   aForm = New Form1
                   Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab) = aForm
                   Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab).Show()
               Case 1
                   aForm = Nothing
                   aForm = New Form2
                   Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab) = aForm
                   aForm.Show()
               Case 2
                   aForm = Nothing
                   aForm = New Form3
                   Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab) = aForm
                   Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab).Show()
           End Select

       Else
           Cabinet.Item(indexOfCab).Show()
       End If

   End If
```

**End Sub**

Comment: I tried to comment with some code, but couldn't get it to work right - please take a look at my alternative answer.